# How do I add urls from a Django app module into my main urls.py?

Tags: python, django

Hi So I'm learning a course but it's a bit date on Django 1 and I'm using Django 3. (I'm a newbie so didn't realize the difference)

In one section, it says in my accounts app to make a new module for passwords. Then to create an **init**.py file and an urls.py.

I've done this and I"ve created very standard Urls for password reset and change. And have also included the new templates in my project root directory templates folder under registration.

This is my urls. py in my accounts/passwords folder

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name='accounts.passwords'

urlpatterns  = [
path('password/change/', 
        auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), 
        name='password_change'),
path('password/change/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), 
        name='password_change_done'),
path('password/reset/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset'),
path('password/reset/done/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_done'),
path('password/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('password/reset/complete/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

In my main urls.py I've added

```
path('accounts/', include("accounts.passwords.urls")),
```

When I try it out it says there is no reverse match for the name, etc Password_reset_done.

When I put the urls/paths directly into my main urls.py it works.

So I wanted to check, how do I include the urls from a module in an app?

I gave the app_name as "accounts.passwords" and also added that as an app in the settings on my main. Just thought I'd try.

I've tried to google this but couldn't find an answer

Thanks

Comment: The name is `password_change_done` (not `Password_change_done`), so with a lowercase character.

Comment: Furthermore since you defined an `app_name`, you access the view as `accounts.passwords:password_change_done`.

Comment: Hi could I check, Is it okays to define the app_name as accounts.passwords? It's a module within my accounts app. I can't access the url in the browser though if I try to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/change/done/